# Scrapy save duplicate documents in mongodb [pymongo], how to prevent it from duplicating documents

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

spider was ok but now suddenly it is inserting duplicate documents

```
#Pipeline
import pymongo


class BucketPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient(
            'localhost',
            27017
        )
        db = self.conn['buc']
        self.collection = db['product']

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

## spider

[spider function here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYA9L.png)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent duplication, you need to find a unique identifier for each item, it's often already present from the webpage or JSON data you crawled.

Then, for each item, you may want to assign `_id` field with value of the identifier you found, since *MongoDB* uses it as the primary key.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html

It is also viable to create a *unique index* in *MongoDB* for the key name of the identifier.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique

Comment: i tried every thing but did not work , and i just remove the code for downloading images, now its working fine, idk why

Comment: when i was downloading images this error occur
 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 400): Error downloading file from <GET https:/